# How to remove a part of a url in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of urls which have varying numbers in the end after an `&` sign. I'm not able to apply a regex to remove these numbers (including the `&`) from the url as there are multiple & in the string and the `re.sub('&\d*',"",x)` command filters all of the `&`  including the one I want to remove.

The url is: `http://helloworld.com?p1=123&p2=987&hello=world&123456`

The desired output I want is: `http://helloworld.com?p1=123&p2=987&hello=world`

Comment: Also as a side note I think you mean to be using forward slashes in your urls like this `http://` not back slashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an anchored pattern if you always want the last parameter:

```
re.sub(r'&\d+$',"",x)
```

The important piece is the dollar sign which says to only match at the end.

Also you should keep in mind that whenever you use `*` that can match the empty string. If you want to match a non-empty string, you need to use `+`.

Comment: @Kasra your answer is wrong because you still may match something in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You need `+` after `\d` for match! When you use `&\d*`, it first matches the middle `&`. Also, you need a `$` to specify that your pattern is at the end of the string:

```
'http:\\helloworld.com?p1=123&p2=987&hello=world&123456'
                             ^
```

so use `re.sub(r'(&\d+)$',"",x)` instead of yours! See [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cN7kC6/2).

Comment: In general it is best to use raw strings when specifying regexes using `r''`